# How can I execute a mysql request on click?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

```
<?php
        require 'connect.inc.php';
        $query = "SELECT `item`, `up`, `down` FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);

        if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

            while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
                $item = $query_row['item'];
                $up = $query_row['up'];
                $down = $query_row['down'];
    ?>  
    <div id="one">
        <div id="votes">
            <?php
                echo "$up votes";
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="or">
        <div id="item">
            <?php echo $item ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <div id="votes">
            <?php
                echo "$down votes";
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php       }

        } else {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
        ?>
```

This is my code. I need to make it so when a user clicks the div id="one" or id="two" execute this sql query (if div one was clicked (same thing for two))

```
UPDATE mytable SET up=$up+1 WHERE id="1(can be any id)"
```

Also, can I do that math in an sql query?

Thanks

Comment: There is not a concise answer to your question. You will need to listen for the click event (Javascript), send a request to the script (AJAX), handle the request with a modified version of your script (PHP, remove the HTML UI output), return an appropriate response (PHP) and handle the response (Javascript). You will need to study the available documentation and perhaps follow a tutorial or three to gain the ability to do this.

Comment: Cole Farmer, you'll need to either make another page to do an ajax call to or do an ajax call on that correct page, if you want i will show you how.

Comment: @NetaMeta Yeah! if you could send an example, or any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Never use the same 'id' attribute for more than one element in HTML (there are two divs with "votes" id).

Comment: @jpatiaga Is there a reason? they have the exact same attributes.

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be unique. A `class` is for common elements. In your CSS, you'd style an `id` like `div#myid { ... }`, and a class like `div.myclass { ... }`. Consider the JS function `document.getElementById('myid')` - this would fail if you had 2 `id`'s the same.

Comment: @ColeFarmerJohnson http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 2):

Alright so this consist of 3 parts:

1.html.
2.JS/ajax.
3.php.

1.) HTML.

```
<div data-action="up" class="clicker" id="<?php echo $item; ?>">
    <div id="votes">
        <?php
            echo "$up votes";
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="or">
    <div id="item">
        <?php echo $item ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-action="down" class="clicker" id="<?php echo $item; ?>">
    <div id="votes">
        <?php
            echo "$down votes";
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

2.) JS/Ajax.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' >
$('.clicker').click(function (){ 
    doAjaxCall($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('data-action'));
});

function doAjaxCall(varID, vote){
    var pageUrl = document.URL;
    ar post = '{"ajax":"yes", "varID":' + varID + ', "vote":' + vote + '}';// Incase you want to pass dynamic ID
    $.post(pageUrl,post,function(data){
        var response = $.parseJSON( data )
        if(response.success){
            //do whatever you like.
            alert('baaaam');
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

3.) php.

```
if($_POST['ajax'] == 'yes'){
    $field = $_POST['vote'];
    $query = "UPDATE mytable SET `$field` = `$field` +1 WHERE id=".$_POST['var_id'];
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);
    $return = array();
    $return['success'] = false;
    if($query_run){
       $return['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
    die()
}
```

**Update whole Page**

```
if($_POST['ajax'] == 'yes'){
    $field = $_POST['vote'];
    $query = "UPDATE mytable SET `$field` = `$field` +1 WHERE id=".$_POST['var_id'];
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);
    $return = array();
    $return['success'] = false;
    if($query_run){
       $return['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
    die()
}


$query = "SELECT `item`, `up`, `down` FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
$item = $query_row['item'];
$up = $query_row['up'];
$down = $query_row['down'];

?>
<div data-action="up" class="clicker" id="<?php echo $item; ?>">
    <div id="votes">
        <?php
            echo "$up votes";
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="or">
    <div id="item">
        <?php echo $item ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-action="down" class="clicker" id="<?php echo $item; ?>">
    <div id="votes">
        <?php
            echo "$down votes";
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' >
$('.clicker').click(function (){ 
    doAjaxCall($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('data-action'));
});

function doAjaxCall(varID, vote){
    var pageUrl = document.URL;
    var post = '{"ajax":"yes", "varID":' + varID + ', "vote":' + vote + '}';// Incase you want to pass dynamic ID
    $.post(pageUrl,post,function(data){
        var response = $.parseJSON( data )
        if(response.success){
            //do whatever you like.
            alert('baaaam');
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
<?php       }

    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    ?>
```

Basically this is the whole thing. if you want i can also put the pieces together for you.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I think I can do the rest myself, but it wouldn't hurt to see how you would do it.

Comment: Ahha i think i see what you did.. in down it holds the down votes, and in up it holds the up votes.. why did you not just set 1 fields called votes and just up/ down the count ?

Comment: The layout of the site calls for showing both up votes and down votes.

Comment: I can't seem to figure this. How would I put the pieces together?

Comment: They are together now, at the very top you check if ajax call was done, if yes, you use the post variable to do your up/down sql query,  and in the bottom i bind a click to call the ajax for each of the buttons, a up button have action up, and down has a down action, those action are passed to ajax and to the php script which translate to the name of the fields. so basically if a up button was click, item(which i assume is the raw id) and up will be posted to the same page, i then take the id and the "up" and set them as the up/down field, and the id goes to the where..

Answer (score 0):

You can add and `onClick()` event in javascript/jquery. Then, do a POST like this

```
$("#div1").onClick(function(){
   var info = $(this).val();
   $.post("fileWithQuery.php",{toUpdate: info},function(data){  // (fileName to post, variables to send via POST, callBack function)
      // Show a message
   });
});
```

You just need to create that php file.

Comment: Somewhere on here I read that I can't run a sql query with jQuery. Is that true?

Comment: You can't run queries because jQuery runs at client's computers, but, you can do a POST send the required information, run the query and make a callBack function